# Падает сборка проекта на Travis ci

Tags: java, travis, liquibase

Выдает такую ошибку , что может быть причиной ?

Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (default) on project tracker: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused -> [Help 1]

перевод - Не удалось выполнить цель org.liquibase: Liquibase-maven-plugin: 3.6.2: обновление (по умолчанию) в трекере проекта: Ошибка при настройке или запуске Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: подключение к локальному хосту : 5432 отказался. Убедитесь, что имя хоста и порт указаны правильно, и что почтмейстер принимает соединения TCP / IP. В соединении отказано -> [Справка 1]

Comment: Так и что тут непонятного?) При сборке видимо проект как-то запускается и пробует подключиться к БД, а потом падает, т.к. БД нет на localhost'е

Comment: Ну это я понял) просто где надо искать ошибку ? На компе проект нормально собирается

Comment: ошибки нет, при сборке либо подключайте удаленную БД, либо БД должна идти в зависимостях к сборке.

Comment: services:
    - postgresql

  before_install:
    - psql -c 'create database tracker;' -U postgres  это есть у меня в travis.yml это зависимость ?

Comment: да, но тогда в параметрах подключения  нужно указать этот сервис. возможно вместо localhost подставить postgresql (хз что у вас за проект, но в спринге типа `--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql/tracker`